# R - Leaflet WMTS layer is not rendering

Tags: r, leaflet, maps

I'm working on adding a WMTS layer to my R Leaflet map using this url:

https://mrdata.usgs.gov/mapcache/wmts?layer=alteration&service=WMTS&request=GetCapabilities&version=1.0.0

I add the url into my code under the "addWMSTiles" option in R Leaflet like such:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

ui <- shinyUI(
fluidPage(
    leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "900px")
)
)

server <- function(input, output) {

output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
        addTiles() %>%
        setView(-93.65, 42.0285, zoom = 4) %>%
        addWMSTiles("https://mrdata.usgs.gov/mapcache/wmts?layer=alteration&service=WMTS&request=GetCapabilities&version=1.0.0",
            layers = "sim3340",
            options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png", transparent = TRUE),
            attribution = "")
})
}

app <- shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
runApp(app, launch.browser = TRUE)
```

When I run this code the map will display in the browser but all that displays is the base leaflet (OpenStreets) Map (image below).

[image]

When there should be some coloring around CA and AZ since that's that WMTS layer is highlighting.

At first I thought it may be due to there being 3 different projection matrices in the WMTS layer but even if I call crs = "EPSG:6.3:3857" in the addWMSTiles options it still shows up as the base map.

What do I need to change or add to make this WMTS layer show up on the map?

Thank you and as always any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it. The call to your `baseUrl` was not correct.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "900px")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      setView(-93.65, 42.0285, zoom = 4) %>%
      addWMSTiles(baseUrl = "https://mrdata.usgs.gov/mapcache/wms/",
                  layers = "sim3340",
                  options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png", transparent = TRUE),
                  attribution = "")
  })
}

app <- shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
runApp(app, launch.browser = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you! I see you're using the WMS layer...does leaflet in R not work with WMTS layers?

Comment: I think it is using the wms as a WMTS. If you zoom in, you will see different Tiles. Check out [this page](https://aagarw30.gitbooks.io/r-leaflet/1_5_add3tiles.html) for further examples.